# Magento 2 - checkout/#shipping Order of form items

Tags: magento2, shipping

Order of form items

Which file to change the order of form inputs?

Comment: Which input fields need to be reordered?

Comment: phone field, needs to be after lastname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update the layout file of checkout in your theme:

> app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

or in custom module:

> app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

---

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="telephone" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">70</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

The sort order may be different depending on your needs.

**PS:** Don't replace the whole layout file, just add this part of the tree in the same place (or only change the value of `sortOrder`  if this part already here):

```
<item name="telephone" xsi:type="array">          
    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">70</item>
</item>
```